# pandas: column order changed after merging multiple data frames

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge, outer-join

I am using the following code to merge the following a list of data frames on the time column.

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['time'], how='outer'), df_list).fillna(-1)
```

Most of the time, `time` is the first column of the merged data frame. However, sometimes, I got other column becomes the first column like `Lab-032` column below:

```
    Lab-032         time    Lab-031 Lab-028 Lab-025 Lab-029 Lab-030 Lab-027
0   -1.000  1520595660.000  26.500  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000
1   -1.000  1520595720.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000
2   -1.000  1520595780.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  20.000  -1.000  43.000
3   -1.000  1520595840.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  9.667   -1.000
4   -1.000  1520595900.000  -1.000  -1.000  5.000   -1.000  -1.000  -1.000
5   -1.000  1520595960.000  -1.000  10.333  24.667  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000
6   -1.000  1520596020.000  24.000  17.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000  -1.000
```

Why is this happening and how do I avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: what are the order of columns in the members of `df_list`?  You could always do `df_merged.set_index('time').sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()`